# Is there any API for constraint based programming in java

Tags: java, constraints

Is there any API available for Constraint Based programming in java.

Comment: http://www.emn.fr/z-info/choco-solver/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went down a similar path and came across [JOpt](http://jopt.sourceforge.net/).  The project is probably worth your attention, but one of the maintainers of that project pointed me to a more mature and active project called [Choco](http://choco.sourceforge.net/), which isn't mentioned in the Wikipedia article.  More recent versions of Choco create a clear separation between the constraint model specification and the solver.  For a quick overview, you may be interested in reviewing [Choco's documentation](http://choco.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/choco/trunk/src/site/resources/tex/documentation/choco-doc.pdf).

As a Java programmer interested in constraint-based programming, you might want to check out [JSR 331](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=331), a specification for a constraint-based programming API packaged under javax.constraints.  (Choco is involved in the coregulation of this JSR.)

Comment: This question is over a year old, but I just read it today; do you maybe know JaCoP as well and know how it compares to Choco, efficiency-wise and in terms of being bug-free?

Comment: I haven't tried JaCoP. I recently implemented a non-trivial solution using Choco, and while I did get it to work well eventually, I found the implementation process to be very… brittle. If I were to start over, I'd probably try JaCoP instead.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia has some links to Java libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming#Constraint_programming_libraries_for_imperative_programming_languages), for example.

Comment: i found this useful got some new API's